# On startup: play ppt slideshow on secondary screen in fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, boot, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I intend to have a slideshow running on my secondary screen upon startup (once the user is logged in). Preferably a slideshow displaying a PowerpointPresentation, but a slideshow with PDF might do as well. It should not answer to any keys or such. Just run the presentation impervious to anything the user does on the main screen.

The Microsoft PowerpointViewer basically seems to be what I need (i.e. run a .ppt in fullscreen). But I am unable to make it go into fullscreen on the secondary screen (it always goes for the primary screen).
Also, how would I make it impervious to any input by the user and make it startup automatically?